# No se me agrupa bien la consulta SQL

Tags: sql

```
 select count(*),(select p.nombre from pais p where p.id=d.pais_id),r.tipo_doc,(select m.nombre 
 from moneda m where m.id= r.moneda_id),sum(d.montante) 
 from documento d 
 left join remesa r 
 on r.id = d.remesa_id 
 left join envio_remesa er 
 on er.id = r.envio_remesa_id
 where er.id = 3
 group by d.pais_id, r.tipo_doc, r.moneda_id, d.montante
```

El caso es que en mi consulta aparecen nombres repetidos cuando deberían estar agrupados, he hecho un group by pero parece que no está funcionando. ¿Alguien sabe que puede estar pasando?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir, por ejemplo, los dos primeros registros que se ven en la imagen de nombre Australia deberían estar agrupados porque tienen el mismo nombre de país, el mismo tipo de doc, nombre de moneda, y se debería hacer la suma de ambos montantes

Comment: fijate que haces el group by de varios conceptos, en el caso de CANADA, la moneda es diferente, y agrupas por este campo, por lo tanto, seran registros distintos

Comment: @Srsole Sí pero en el caso de Canadá está bien

Comment: es el que nos señalas

Comment: en el caso de finlandia lo mismo, pero con el SUM

Comment: Creo que deberias cambiar tu pregunta, añadir los datos de tu tabla y explicar bien lo que estas tratando de hacer.

Comment: @Srsole En mi opinión está bien explicado. Estoy intentando agrupar por el nombre de un país, de una moneda y por el tipo_doc. Como he explicado, en los dos primeros registros que saca la consulta con nombre Australia, debería ser un solo registro unido ya que coinciden los campos de estas tres propiedades, además sumar el montante de estos registros

Comment: nada de lo que comentas aqui esta en la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creo que el problema lo tienes en meter

> d.montante

dentro del group by.
Como después estás haciendo una operación de agregado SUM ese dato no necesitas meterlo en el group by.

Comment: Efectivamente, ese era el problema, gracias

Comment: básicamente lo puesto en el comentario